# golang gin router use middleware，how to bind body multiple times？

Tags: go, go-gin

golang gin router use middleware，how to bind body multiple times？

```golang
func (a AkSk) Check(c *gin.Context) {
    paramsDealed := map[string]string{}

    if err := c.ShouldBind(&paramsDealed); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, apis.NewResult(http.StatusUnauthorized, false, err.Error(), ""))
        c.Abort()
    }
}
```

```golang
func Controller(c *gin.Context) {
    param := params.Params{}
    err := c.BindJSON(&param)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, apis.NewResult(http.StatusBadRequest, false, err.Error(), map[string]interface{}{}))
        return
    }
}
```

The second time results in the error EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ShouldBindBodyWith](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1#Context.ShouldBindBodyWith). It stores the request body into the context, and reuse when it is called again.

See [Try to bind body into different structs](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/bind-body-into-dirrerent-structs/) for more information.